# Delphi проект: один из классов компоненты не распознается при открытии формы

Tags: delphi

Вопрос у меня довольно сложный для восприятия, но постараюсь понятнее. Проект создан не мной, чужой код.

Есть проект `DelphiMain.dpr`, содержит несколько форм. Каждой форме соответствуют модули `Unit1.dcu, Unit1.dfm, Unit1.pas Unit1.ddp ... Unit9.dcu, Unit9.dfm, Unit9.dfm, Unit9.ddp`. Всего форм 9.
Проект содержит пользовательский компонент `DelphiCOM.dsk`. Этот компонент включает в себя 6 классов: `TUCSCOM1 ... TUCSCOM6`. Для каждого составляющего: `UCSCOM1.dcu, UCSCOM1.pas ... UCSCOM6.dcu, UCSCOM6.pas`.
В каждом из модулей `UCSCOM1 - UCSCOM6`:

```
procedure Register;
begin
   RegisterComponents('DelphiMain', [TUCSCOM1]);
end;
...
procedure Register;
begin
   RegisterComponents('DelphiMain', [TUCSCOM6]);
end;
```

В главной форме `Unit1.pas` в начале прописан

```
uses UCSCOM1, UCSCOM2, UCSCOM3, UCSCOM4, UCSCOM5, UCSCOM6;
```

Но - при попытке открытия формы `Unit1.dfm` ошибка:

> TUCSCOM6 не обнаружен!

В графическом виде форма `Unit.dfm` не открывается, можно посмотреть только текстовый вид...

Все модули - в одной директории, по идее друг друга видят.
Проект вместе с компонентами билдится без ошибок, экзешник строится и запускается. Но при работе вылетает куча Run-Time эрроров, поскольку главная форма по прежнему не видит `TUCSCOM6`, а элементы такого типа в ней есть.

Есть такая зацепка - ПОЧЕМУ-ТО ДЛЯ `TUCSCOM6` ЕСТЬ МОДУЛЬ `TUCSCOM6.dsk`. Хотя он является частью компоненты.
Для `TUCSCOM1` - `TUCSCOM5` `dsk` файлов нет!

Comment: может DelphiCOM.dpk?

Comment: пакет в IDE загружен? компоненты в палитре присутствуют? приложение компилируется с пакетами?

Comment: Вы не уточнили самое главное - установлены ли эти компоненты в IDE. Файлы dsk - идут лесом, они "левые". Вам нужен либо .dpk либо инсталлить компоненты по одному, раз у них у всех есть register.

Comment: Гуглите как устанавливать компоненты в Delphi.

Comment: "может DelphiCOM.dpk" - нет, DPK точно нигде нет.

Comment: Компонентов в палитре нет... Наверно все так, но меня смущает, почему все это так до меня сделали и все билдится...

Comment: Короче, я пытаюсь установить DelphiCOM по инструкции, которую нашел, но при попытке открыть DelphiCOM.dpk у меня все та же ошибка - TUCSCOM6 не обнаружен!

Comment: Что можно сделать?

Comment: @AVM "DPK точно нигде нет", "попытке открыть DelphiCOM.dpk" - так есть у Вас проект пакета (dpk) или нет?

Comment: DelphiCOM.dpk - есть, все правильно. То была опечатка. Хотел исправить, да править можно только в течение 5 мин (

Comment: @AVM - инструкция/ссылка не скопировалась

Comment: А вы в эту ссылку добавьте пробелы и снова вставьте ее. Уж пожалуйста, мне это очень важно.

Comment: @AVM В какую ссылку? Я имел в виду, что в Вашем комментарии никакой ссылки не было, так что "добавлять пробелы" мне некуда.

Comment: Пардон, вот ссылка: http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=44366